# how to turn LIKE'%%' into user input

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

hi I am trying to create a store locator and part finder, ATM I have an sql query that uses LIKE to get all answer that have 1 in this is connected to the php input as well how would I change the LIKE'%%' clause from being specific to being whatever the user puts into the form but obtaining the same results as what the like gives me so if i type in 1 it shows all the parts with one if i type in 4 it does the same. my code is:

```
<head>
        <?php
        $serverName = "127.0.0.0";
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"id", "PWD"=>"pwd");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
        if( $conn === false ) 
        {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        $sql = "SELECT     dbo.Customer.name, dbo.Customer.address1, dbo.Customer.address2, dbo.Customer.address3, dbo.Customer.city, dbo.Customer.state, dbo.Customer.zip, 
                           dbo.Customer.faxnum, dbo.Customer.phonenum, dbo.Customer.emailaddress, Part.description, Part.partnum, ROUND(odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925) ,2)AS distances
                FROM       dbo.Customer INNER JOIN
                           CustomerPartCrossRef ON dbo.Customer.company = CustomerPartCrossRef.company AND dbo.Customer.shiptonum = CustomerPartCrossRef.shiptonum AND 
                           dbo.Customer.custnum = CustomerPartCrossRef.custnum INNER JOIN
                           Part ON CustomerPartCrossRef.partnum = Part.partnum AND CustomerPartCrossRef.company = Part.company
                WHERE      Part.partnum LIKE '%%' AND (ROUND(odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925),2) <= 150)
                ORDER BY   distances ";

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        if( $stmt === false) 
        {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        echo $row['name']."<br/>".$row['address1']."<br/>".$row['state']."<br/>".$row['zip']."<br/>".$row['phonenum']."<br/>".$row['distances']."<br/>".$row['partnum']."<br/>"
        .$row['description']."<br/>";
        }
        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
        ?>
</head>
    <body>
        part = <?php echo $_POST["part"];?>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest that you use PDO rather than the `sqlsrv_*()` functions. Here is such an example:

```
$sql = "SELECT     dbo.Customer.name, dbo.Customer.address1, dbo.Customer.address2, dbo.Customer.address3, dbo.Customer.city, dbo.Customer.state, dbo.Customer.zip, 
                           dbo.Customer.faxnum, dbo.Customer.phonenum, dbo.Customer.emailaddress, Part.description, Part.partnum, ROUND(odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925) ,2)AS distances
                FROM       dbo.Customer INNER JOIN
                           CustomerPartCrossRef ON dbo.Customer.company = CustomerPartCrossRef.company AND dbo.Customer.shiptonum = CustomerPartCrossRef.shiptonum AND 
                           dbo.Customer.custnum = CustomerPartCrossRef.custnum INNER JOIN
                           Part ON CustomerPartCrossRef.partnum = Part.partnum AND CustomerPartCrossRef.company = Part.company
                WHERE      Part.partnum LIKE '%?%' AND (ROUND(odbcadmin.fn_calDist(- 0.03715491813985, 0.9178158214586024, long * 0.0174532925, lat * 0.0174532925),2) <= 150)
                ORDER BY   distances ";
$dbh = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['users_input']));
```

When `execute()` is called the `?` I have added into your query will be replaced by the value in the array. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php for more information.

Obviously you would probably want to validate the user input before passing it into `execute()`.

Comment: errrrm just to let you now i didnt understand a word of any of that im new to microsoft sql

Comment: the answer was more related to php than to sql.

Comment: how would i use Treffynnons code in mine what would i need to take out ?? and also what is the DB_Port ?? i have never used this before

Comment: @Pazrat I have updated the answer and removed the port as SQL Server doesn't require it. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: why did you edit the code ?? im not using a local data base does this matter and i updated the code at the top to my full code how would i implement yours into it what would i remove ??